# Nash Inequality

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, holder-inequality

As an exercise from my book I wanted to prove:

> For $n>2$ and for any $u \in W_0^{1,2}\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right) \cap L^1\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$,
> $$
> \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\nabla u|^2 d x \geq c\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u^2 d x\right)^{\frac{n+2}{n}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|u| d x\right)^{-\frac{4}{n}},
> $$
> where $c=c(n)>0$.

I solved a similar problem and used an appropriate Hölder inequality and the Sobolev inequality in the form
$$
\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|u|^{\frac{2 n}{n-2}} d x\right)^{\frac{n-2}{n}} \leq C \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\nabla u|^2 d x
$$
and I think it works here too, I just cannot find the fitting exponents. Any hints on how to tackle this one?

Comment: Apply Holder to $\int u^2$ and then Sobolev to one of the resulting factors.

Comment: @Deane I did the same for the Poincaré Inequality, the problem is how to get that term with $-4/n$.

Comment: Move it to the other side.

Comment: @Deane I made an edit and tried to use Hölder

Comment: You applied Holder to $(u)(1)$. That won't work. In particular, the constant will not depend on the volume of $\Omega$.

Comment: @Deane Ok I got it, there was some work left though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Hölder's inequality
$$
\int |u|^2 = \int |u|^{\frac{4}{n+2} + \frac{2n}{n-2}\frac{n-2}{n+2}}
\\
\leq \left(\int |u|\right)^\frac{4}{n+2} \left(\int |u|^\frac{2n}{n-2}\right)^\frac{n-2}{n+2}
$$
By Sobolev's inequality, which reads (notice a mistake in your question about the exponent)
$$
\left(\int |u|^\frac{2n}{n-2}\right)^\frac{n-2}{n} \leq C_n \int |\nabla u|^2
$$
this implies
$$
\int |u|^2 \leq C_n^\frac{n}{n+2}\left(\int |u|\right)^\frac{4}{n+2} \left(\int |\nabla u|^2\right)^\frac{n}{n+2}
$$
or equivalently
$$
\left(\int |u|^2\right)^\frac{n+2}{n} \leq C_n\left(\int |u|\right)^\frac{4}{n} \int |\nabla u|^2.
$$